# Cannot setText to TextView in Android

Tags: android

I am having real problems trying to set a text to TextView on my android application.  The string that I am trying to display was passed to another activity via an intent.  I seem to have successfully retrieved this extra from the intent  but i am failing to attach it to my TextView.  Please can someone help?  i am using fragments throughout.

All I am getting is my layout display without the Text that i am trying to assign.

```
Fragment:2

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_fragment, parent, false);

    journalTitle = (String) getArguments().getString(EXTRA_JOURNALTITLE); // extra from intent
    Log.d("onCreateView", "a.getJournalTitle: " + journalTitle); // this works. displays in logCat

    journalTitleView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.journalTitle_articleFragment_textView);
    journalTitleView.setText(journalTitle);
```

Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/journalTitle_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="journal title"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pubYear_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/journalTitle_articleFragment_textView"
    android:text="pubYear"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/volume_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pubYear_articleFragment_textView"
    android:text="volume"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/issue_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/volume_articleFragment_textView"
    android:text="issue"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pageInfo_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/issue_articleFragment_textView"
    android:text="pageInfo"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/journalTitle_articleFragment_textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="article title"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/authorString_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="authors"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/abstractText_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/authorString_articleFragment_textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="abstractText"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: can you post the layout?

Comment: try somethink like . not a soln but.. set text property in xml n getText in code and see in logcat and Ui. and then append some string and check again.

Comment: Are you getting an Exception?  Does your article_fragment.xml have a TextView with the id journalTitle_articleFragment_textView?

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions. my activity is generated successfully , but the text that is displayed is not what i am trying to assign but what is present in the layout paramter android:text

Comment: Try changing the text color to black. Sounds silly but many have been though this situation.

Comment: I'm getting a display. what is displayed is the values from "android:text" rather than what I am trying to assign

Comment: @user3274549 is textbox dispalying **journal title**?

Comment: yes. that is what is displayed.

Comment: @user3274549 try to test it with `journalTitleView.setText("test message");`

Comment: its still displays "journal title"

Comment: @user3274549 did you add `return v;` and also clear your project may help.

Comment: yes id did. return v is present at the end of the method

Answer (score 1):

In onCreateView you should only inflate your layout and return it:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_fragment, parent, false);
return v;
```

Your textView modifications should be moved to **onViewCreated**

Comment: Have you moved this line -journalTitleView = (TextView) v           .findViewById(R.id.journalTitle_articleFragment_textView), to onViewCreated, and using its returned view public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)?

Comment: public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  journalTitle = (String) getArguments().getString(EXTRA_JOURNALTITLE);
  Log.d("onCreateView", "journalTitle value: " + journalTitle);

  journalTitleView2 = (TextView) v
    .findViewById(R.id.journalTitle_articleFragment_textView);
  journalTitleView2.setText(journalTitle);

 }

Answer (score 0):

Try :

TextView journalTitleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.journalTitle_articleFragment_textView);
   journalTitleView.setText(journalTitle);

Comment: that is exactly what i have done. Please not that I have already defined TextView journalTitleView; at the top of the document (not shown here)

Comment: remove v from code: TextView journalTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.journalTitle_articleFragment_textView); journalTitleView.setText(journalTitle);

Comment: i'm using fragments so removing the v incurs errors. i think you can do that when using activities only

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this code :

```
public static void changeFragmentTextView(String s) {
    Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragment);
    ((TextView) frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.ournalTitle_articleFragment_textView)).setText(s);  
}`
```